# Randomly sample based on values in a list/table with matching structure

Tags: r, dplyr, sample

I have a specific sampling task in R, that I can't figure out how to solve.

I have a 20000x10 list of integer indexes [1:20000, 1:10] called "index", a 20000x10 list of numeric distances [1:20000, 1:10] called "dist" - these are stored together in a list called "x2xx". And I have a separate 20000x1 list of numeric values called "y2xx". I should add that the distances in dist are ordered, with the lowest distances being in column 1 and the highest in column 10.

The indexes in "index" reference row numbers in "y2xx", so that results can be pulled from the y2xx list based on those indexes.

Where all of the dist values in a row of 10 are above 0.75, I would like to take the lowest distance in that row, find the corresponding index in "index" (which should be in the same position) and pull the corresponding value from y2xx.

Where there are distances in a row that are below 0.75, I would like to randomly sample from those indexes/values.

Here is an example:

dist:

```
0.81  0.82  0.82  0.83  0.91  0.95  1.01  1.05  1.10  1.25
0.72  0.79  0.92  0.92  0.92  0.92  0.92  0.92  1.14  1.54
0.01  0.01  0.04  0.03  0.24  0.73  0.79  0.80  0.84  1.12
```

index:

```
1233  3805  3813  5835  2765  5300  5482  7768  2072  4684
2588  2623  8184  3429  0397  2306  2441  3805  7163  8351
0057  1005  3919  6552  3410  9594  0100  0839  8676  9318
```

For row 1, I would want to get the value from row 1233 of "y2xx".

For row 2, I would want to get the value from row 2588 of "y2xx".

For row 3, I would want to randomly sample one of the values from rows 57, 1005, 3919, 6552, 3410 and 9594 of "y2xx".

I have figured out a way to randomly sample from all 10 of the values in the row using this code:

```
results <- apply(matrix(y2yy[x2xx$index], ncol=10), 1, sample, 1)
```

But I can't figure out a way to sample based on the distances in "dist". Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say `x2xx` is a list containing elements `index` and `dist`. `y2xx` is a list of numeric values (why not a numeric vector? who knows?).

First let us write a function that does what you want when applied to a row *i*.

```
getvalue <- function(i, x2xx) {
  dist.row <- x2xx$dist[i,]
  if(all(dist.row > 0.75)) {
    j <- which.min(dist.row)
   } else {
    sel <- which(dist.row <= 0.75)
    j <- sample(sel, 1)
   }

   ret <- x2xx$index[i,j]
}
```

Now all that remains is to apply this function to all rows:

```
sel.idx <- sapply(1:nrow(x2xx$index), getvalue, x2xx=x2xx)
```

and to get the values from y2xx

```
unlist(y2xx)[sel.idx]
```

You did not provide an example for `y2xx`, but here is the generated `sel.idx`:

```
> sel.idx
[1] 1233 2588   57
```